# docker image layers reuploaded each time

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

I've been using the google container registry for a few weeks now and there is one thing that is extremely annoying and that I can' get rid of:

I have one docker image which doesn't change at all, except the last layer, a mere 1MB that is updated regularly. When I push this image regularly to dockerhub, as expected, it tells me all layers already exists except the last one.
When I push to google registry, it reuploads everything, just like it was a brand new image.
I would not mind too much if I was not paying for the network traffic, but as I pay + it takes a long time to upload, is that a known bug?

Answer (score 1):

We recently deployed an update to our registry which implemented support for cross-repo mounting which was introduced with the Docker 1.10.x client. This should also solve the duplicate blob push issue that you were observing.

Comment: I changed my images and i didn't get any further duplicate issues.
I will update this thread if I have further issues.

Answer (score 0):

We are aware of the regression in docker pushes to the Google Container Registry and are actively investigating the issue.

Thank you for patience.